# Plugins upload to wordpress in wampserver via filezilla

Tags: plugins, ftp

I am new to Wordpress. I just downloaded a plugin. I am trying to upload plugins the normal way but they are unable.

So my quiz is, can you upload plugins in Wordpress to wampserver via filezilla? If so, how should I go about it.

Comment: Please have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Installing_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin you have downloaded is zipped, unzip the file and upload the folder into your wp-content/plugins folder in the WordPress installation. It should appear in the admin for you to activate.